# Need advice on password hashing algorithm for Flask security module

Tags: security, flask, cryptography, password-hash, flask-security

In one of my flask project I'm using [Flask-security](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/) module for security mechanism. In module configuration I have 3 choices for password hashing algorithm **bcrypt, sha512_crypt, pbkdf2_sha512**.

Can any one suggest me which to use and why?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of these are acceptable choices. I prefer bcrypt, because it's GPU unfriendly, so an attacker won't have a big advantage when they use a GPU while your server uses a CPU to hash.

Make sure to choose a work factor that's as big as possible while offering acceptable performance. Should be somewhere between 10 and 100ms for typical web servers.